# how to capture and alter all outgoing requests from a flex application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, request

currently in my flex application, I've got all of the app's assets being served from my local server, but I want to be able to serve all of the assets from a CDN (e.g. my.awesomeCDN.com)

the application has quite a bit of components so rather than going to each component and changing the source of the asset, is there a way to capture all of the outgoing request from my flex application and run some logic where I can change the request from http://localhost/images to http://my.awesomeCDN.com/images?

Comment: Think the best way to achieve this is to use a static const in one of your classes then refer to it throughout like ApplicaitonConstants.baseURL, otherwise the only thing I can think of is to "monkey patch" the HTTPService or WebService or whatever class you were using for establishing the connections, but that just sounds like an awful hack, better to use a static constant you can change in one place and have reflected everywhere (will make upgrading SDKs less painful).

Comment: I think [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) might be able to do that.

Comment: You have a bad design there. You should have made a config singleton class and put the URLs in there And let the singleton class control what URL to use depending on if you are in production or dev

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ApplicationConstants
{
    //public static const baseURL:String = "http://localhost";
    public static const baseURL:String = "http://my.awesomeCDN.com";
}
```

in some other file

```
<s:Image source="{ApplicationConstants.baseURL}/images/somePic.png"/>
```